# what happens to voltage and charge of parallel plate capacitor after removing its source and dielectric

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

I think that capacitance as well as voltage both will change but I have doubt because of capacitor energy storing capacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the source is removed the charge stored on the capacitor $Q$ must be constant.

From the definition of capacitance $Q=CV$ where $C$ is the capacitance and $V$ the potential difference between the plates of the capacitor.
The energy stored is $E= \dfrac {Q^2}{2C}$.
I have chosen this form of the equation because the charge is constant.

If the dielectric is removed from between the plates of the capacitor its capacitance decreases whilst the potential difference between the plates increases, $Q=C\downarrow V\uparrow$.
The energy stored increases $E\uparrow= \dfrac {Q^2}{2C\downarrow}$.
The increase in stored energy comes from the work which needed to be done to remove the dielectric from between the plates of the capacitor.

Comment: No energy is taken away along with the dielectric?

Comment: It is assumed that the dielectric does not retain a permanent polarisation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that capacitors do not store voltage [in fact there is no meaning to such a statement, I edited your question]. Capacitors actually store energy.

When the source is removed, the charge on the capacitor has to be conserved, you see there is nowhere the charge can go. The capacitance does not change since it is a geometrical quantity. Given the area of the plates, the dielectric medium and the distance between the plates, capacitance is constant.

If the dielectric is removed [In this case I am assuming the source is still connected], the charge is conserved, since the source can supply or take in the charge. However, the capacitance decreases.